# JADE - agent hosting webservice (wsdl)

Tags: java, wsdl, agents-jade, agents

I am building a system which utilizes JADE agents to perform certain tasks. I one scenario, one of the agents needs to host a webservice to communicate to a mobile app.

Unfortunately, the port opened by the agent aren't visible to the system. I am using the code to open port 9191 on localhost:

```
    Endpoint.publish("http://" + Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()":9191/QrReceiver", qr);
```

This getLocalHost() routine returns 127.0.1.1 (which is not localhost), but when I force the ip to be 127.0.0.1, I can access the wsdl file on

```
    http://localhost:9191/QrReceiver?wsdl
```

but I cannot use any other device to access anything on this port. Also, a portscanner utility doesn't find this port (but does find ports 1099 and 7778 which are in use by the JADE agents (and container) for interdevice communication).

How can I utilize a JADE agent to host a wsdl-based webservice?

thanks in advance,
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue previously. This may happen because of two things.

1. `Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` method returning your `localhost` address. i.e `127.0.0.1` So your service is hosted locally and only visible to your localhost. It cannot access through the network.

   If you are using static IP address like `192.168.1.1`. Then put it to service endpoint as `Endpoint.publish("http://192.168.1.1:9191/QrReceiver", qr);`, without getting local IP dynamically. Then you will be able to access it over the network.
2. Probably your firewall may block the port `9191`. So make sure that port is free and open to connections.